beginners question, installation
I have installed magento2 2.4.7.
it is running on my dedicated server.
OS: debian 12
nginx
php 8.3.12
mariadb 10.11.6
currently I managed to log in to mag.mydomain.de/adminxxx
The login screen looks normal. but once I log in, it looks like it is missing formatting of the displayed page.
